# what happens on postgres ALTER TABLE when nothing changes?

Tags: postgresql, ddl

When doing administration on big production postgres database, it seems that even such ALTER TABLE -ddl queries cannot be safely run, that should be no-operations?

Has anyone looked into Postgres source codes or have previous knowledge on what happens in such case?

Looking back at what just happened it seems that on query like:
`ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN column TYPE int8;`

- Table statistics disappeared on that column?
- pages were thrown out of cache?

Even though the column type was already in correct type.

What I learned from this is, that all such queries, even if no operation, should be wrapped inside a function that checks, if anything needs to be done.

Comment: That's where schema migration tools (Liquibase, Flyway, squitch, ... ) come into play: they will only run those migrations that are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comment although it didn't answer the actual question.

Comment: To be honest: I am not sure _what_ the question actually is.

Comment: question is: what happens in such case? What does the `ALTER TABLE table ALTER COLUMN column TYPE int8;` change when column type is already int8?

Comment: Looking at the postgres source codes, this might be at least what happens: https://github.com/postgres/postgres/blob/4c8a1b4769372037b28516e5c9acb39bb82fa92d/src/backend/commands/tablecmds.c#L13569

It seems that the function call is executed without checking column type at all.

Comment: I just ran such an ALTER TABLE and it only took 5ms on a table with 5 million rows. Changing from `int` to `bigint` took about 15 seconds, so I assume that nothing is really done on disk in that case

Comment: If the two data types are binary compatible (or identical), the table is not rewritten. With a change from `integer` to `bigint`, the table is rewritten.

Comment: It was my assumption based on similar cases that nothing changes. But even though if data itself won't change, clearing statistics will break query planning until statistics are analyzed again.